# Обработка исключения InputMismatchException

Tags: java, исключения

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                int h = scan.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException h) {
                System.out.println("Enter number");
            }
            int i = h - 1;
            int j = 2;
            if (h >= 0 && h < 23) {
                while (h != 0) {
                    System.out.println(repeat(" ", i) + repeat("#", j));
                    h--;
                    i--;
                    j++;
                }
                break;
            } else
                System.out.println("Incorrect");
        }
    }

    public static String repeat(String s, int i) {
        String str = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            str = str + s;
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Есть программа которая рисует пирамидку заданной пользователем высоты. Она полностью рабочая, но я решил добавить туда обработку исключения если пользователь введет что-то другое вместо цифры. Как бы я не оформлял его вечно что-то не так. Основная ошибка выходит что в последующих строках кода перестала обнаруживаться переменная h, которую я засунул в блок try. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно оформить исключение? Желательно чтобы обработка требовала заново и заново ввести данные пока пользователь не введет число. Заранее благодарен

Comment: Отформатировал код и стало ясно, что код некомпилируемый из-за проблемы создания переменной `int h`, ее ведь область видимости находится только внутри блока try/catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну самый просто способ - сделать примерно так:

```
while (true) {
    int h;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        h = scan.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        continue;
    }
    int i = h - 1;
    int j = 2;
    if (h >= 0 && h < 23) {
        while (h != 0) {
            System.out.println(repeat(" ", i) + repeat("#", j));
            h--;
            i--;
            j++;
        }
        break;
    } else
        System.out.println("Incorrect");
}
```

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы объявляли переменную h внутри блока try, а значит за пределами этого блока ее не видно. В целом ваша задача проверить ее на корректность, если нет - то вы просто запускаете след итерацию цикла, если все ок, то выполняете нужные вам действия

Comment: спасибо большое. Теперь мои познания в области использования исключений немного выросли)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String repeat(String s, int i) {
    //String str = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        String str = str + s;
    }
    return str;
```

Еще подскажите пожалуйста: когда я писал метод я изначально не писал вторую строку и он мне выдавал ошибку что строчная переменная не инициализирована (хотя даже пробовал писать её, но без присвоения "", а в выражении соответственно String убирал). Почему так? Ведь она проинициализирована прямо в выражении. Причем выдавал прямо в этом выражении сразу после знака равно. В строке с return то понятно, там видимо эту переменную не видел метод потому что она внутри цикла инициализирована была